# Optimal literal representation of integers and floats

Tags: floating-point, integer, double, literals

As I understand it, integer literals can be read faster by the computer when they're written in a base that's a power of two, which is why library macros always write them in hexadecimal. Is there a similar way to write floats or doubles so that the computer can read them faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Here's how you do it in C/C++: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal

I believe most languages have support for hexadecimal float representations these days. Note that you cannot write infinity/NaN using this notation, but all other representable floats have an unambiguous and exact representation using this syntax.